# Windows won't detect my Gamepad / Joystick

Tags: controllers, windows-10, windows

I bought a product that's called "BM-707 / BM-727 Bluetooth Android Controller (FW: V
11)

It's said on the manual: "Can be used for PC windows system, TV, box, tablet and Android phones, tablets and IOS phones.."

It also says it supports three types of connections: Blutooth, Wireless (with a receiver), and Wired.

**It does not come with any driver or instruction for driver installation**. I was unable to find one. Please tell me if one exists that you know of

I connect it with the supplied wire - windows won't even detect it as a device. (couldn't find on on Device Manager)

I followed the instruction for connection it via Bluetooth (which works only if the cable is disconnected, apparently) - I managed to convince my PC that the device is connected, and I can even see it in the Device Manager, but the device itself doesn't seem to know it's connecting and clicking buttons on it does nothing. According to the manual, the flashing light (indicating "ready to connect") should stop flashing and indicate "connected" instead.

I'm out of ideas on what to try

Comment: Did you try to calibrate it? I believe Windows 10 still has this functionality.

Comment: What does that mean and how do I do that?

Comment: Go into your Control Panel/Hardware and Sound/Devices and Printers. If Windows recognizes that it's present, it should show up in this list. You should be able to right click on the device, and select "Properties", and one of the tabs in the properties window says "Calibrate". (Or maybe it's a button, I can't recall offhand). Click/select that and follow the instructions.  I know my gamepad would not work until I did this initially.

Comment: I didn't address "what does that mean": Calibration of that device means that Windows will go through the range of values the stick/d-pad and buttons can have, so that it recognizes what "center" is, and which button is mapped to which control signal in the computer. Most modern controllers auto-calibrate, but some of the more fringe devices (like your android-based device) may still require manual calibration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to follow [this](https://www.gearbest.com/blog/how-to/how-to-connect-gen-game-s3-gamepad-to-android-ios-and-pc-1419) guide of connecting it to the Pc. Essentially, it seems that for this controller, even with wireless connection, you need to press and hold the home button, in order for it to be able to connect. That might be also the case for a Bluetooth connection. Normally, almost any Bluetooth device first need to pair with the Pc before it is usable.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about connecting an Xbox controller wirelessly to Windows 10, because Microsoft recently removed the drivers that allow you to do so from their website. You could download drivers that somebody else has made themselves, but that increases the risk of breaking the software of your PC/Laptop and controller from 1 to 10. However, connecting your controller using a charging cable/USB cable is, for sure, a reliable way to use your controller on your PC/Laptop. I don't know how many functions you can carry out, but I know for sure that if you're in a Roblox game and you plug in your controller, it'll convert all the controls **if** the game is compatible for consoles and is available to play on console. The same can be said for Fortnite and it works just as fine and feels like playing just like it does on console but with a smaller screen. I have not tried anything else and do not wish to make assumptions and give you information that may not be true.

Answer (score -1):

You should try connecting it with a cable. If that doesn't work, try restarting the computer. See if it works on your Xbox if you have one. If it does not, maybe your controller is just broken. If it works on the Xbox, it is possible that your computer port is broken. If this does not work, you should try youtube or microsoft support.